# Kendo-ui grid filtering

Tags: angularjs, filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to filter items in a grid by tags, the data in the grid looks like this

```
[
    { id: 0, tags: [{ text: 'boat' }, { text: 'summer' }] },
    { id: 1, tags: [{ text: 'boat' }] },
    { id: 2, tags: [{ text: 'travel' }] },
    { id: 3, tags: [{ text: 'boat' }] },
    { id: 4, tags: [{ text: 'travel' }] },
    { id: 5, tags: [{ text: 'travel' }, { text: 'summer' }] }
]
```

And the function for filtering looks like this

```
$scope.filterGrid = function (e) {
        var grid = $('#imageGrid').data('kendoGrid');
        var val = [{ text: 'travel' }, { text: 'summer' }];
        grid.dataSource.filter({});

        if ($.trim(val) !== '') {
            grid.dataSource.filter({
                logic: 'or',
                filters: [{
                    field: 'tags',
                    operator: function (item) {
                        var status = false;
                        for (var n = 0, length2 = val.length; n < length2; n++) {
                            for (var i = 0, length = item.length; i < length; i++) {
                                if (item[i].text.indexOf(val[n].text) !== -1) {
                                    status = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return status;
                    }
                }]
            });
        }

    };
```

With this example where val = travel, summer i would like to only show the items with both tags (id 5) but it shows all items containing either of the tags (id: 0,2,4,5)

What am i doing wrong and is there a better way to do this with kendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter algorithm was accepting the `item` to have at least one of the two desired values, because the loop break when find one here:

```
if (item[i].text.indexOf(val[n].text) !== -1) {
    status = true;
    break;
}
```

I have changed a little your code to this:

```
operator: function (item) {
    var found = 0;

    for (var i = 0, length = item.length; i < length; i++) {
        for (var n = 0, length2 = val.length; n < length2; n++) {
            if (item[i].text.indexOf(val[n].text) !== -1) {
                found++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return found == val.length;
}
```

It counts the total of found tags(`found`) and return `true` only if the number of found items is the same as the search items(`val.length`). So it starts iterating through `item`, and not through `val`, as the rule stands for *the item has to be all the values*, and not the way around. So for each `item` is performed a check if it has all `val` items and sum `found` counter. At the end, if `found` is equal `val.length` it means that all items on `val` are inside `item`.

[Working demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/etuVu)